# On which stackexchange site do I ask users to code hackertyper for shell?

Tags: support

I was wondering whether someone could code [hackertyper](http://hackertyper.net/) for linux shell. The site code is freely available and also pretty short and simple, so I assume anyone with at least average unix shell knowledge could code it.

What is the appropriate place to ask for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no appropriate Stack Exchange site for "please do this for me" questions (unless, of course, you're looking to hire someone, in which case careers.stackoverflow.com is appropriate).

If you have tried to do it yourself but have run into problems and want to ask a question about your specific issue, then Stack Overflow might be appropriate.

Comment: I still think I could post it to careers.SE, but unfortunately people here on meta seem to be unable to think outside the box. I never said I couldn't pay, did I? But, whatever. If this is the best you guys can do, then let this answer be the accepted one.

Comment: Always happy to improve an answer, so I've edited the answer to include careers.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 10):

Nowhere. Stack Exchange is a Question and Answer platform, not a Do Work For Me platform.

Comment: Uhm, are you sure about that? What about code golf?

Comment: @RiMMER Code Golf is a puzzle solving site. They're not there to write code for problems in general.

Comment: And if anyone ever tries to check in Code Golf-quality code into a project, they're going to hear about it from their co-workers. Loudly. With pitchforks.

Comment: @RiMMER Did you really just ask that? Phrasing your "do work for me" question as a code-golf puzzle is guaranteed to yield the *worst possible solutions* to your problem, every time. It's more of a "do the work for me, but don't do any error handling and don't worry about edge cases and obfuscate the code for me so I can't even understand what my own code does or hope to fix it" site.

Comment: ... Now I want to see if it's possible to write a non-trivial app by chunking the entire thing into code-golf puzzles and trying to cobble the results together.

Comment: @meagar: I don't see what the big deal is here. Obviously you people haven't even seen what hackertyper is and have no humor. It's a simple chunk of code which can be written in like 100 characters for shell and I thought it would be fun to mess around with it. How in the Earth could I possibly make money off of it? I never asked anyone to do a work for me, I just wanted the users to have some fun, but obviously users here don't like fun. Herp derp hurr durr.

Comment: @RiMMER Then post it on code golf. Stack Overflow is not a forum, it has a very *very* specific purpose, and asking people to write code for you is outside the scope of this site. It's not about whether we're interested or not, the site itself does not allow the content you're talking about posting. It is *explicitly prohibited* here, because Stack Overflow **is not a forum**.